# Embedded Images in Signature Not Displaying

Tags: html, image, email, html-email

Attempting to display a company logo in an email signature without it being blocked by default on various email clients. First, I tried uploading the image to the company site, but it returns with this:

[image: ERROR IMAGE]

So then I tried to implement it as a base64 image. It works with Thunderbird...

[image: Yay image]

But it doesn't show in GMail...

[image]

What should I do from here? Source code below...

```
    <div><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" /></div>
<p><span>Griffin Wiebel</span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;Webmaster<br /><a href="https://petrode.com/roundcube/?_task=mail&amp;_action=preview&amp;_uid=9&amp;_mbox=INBOX&amp;_framed=1" target="_blank">303-960-4507</a>/&nbsp;<a href="mailto:griffinwiebel@petrode.com" target="_blank">griffinwiebel@petrode.com</a></p>
<p><span>PetroDE</span>&nbsp;<span>Office:&nbsp;</span><span>123-456-7890</span>&nbsp;<br /><span>2150 W. 6th Avenue, Suite H Broomfield, CO 80020</span><br /><a href="https://petrode.com/" target="_blank">https://petrode.com/</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>This e-mail message may contain confidential or legally privileged information and is intended only for the use of the intended recipient(s). Any unauthorized disclosure, dissemination, distribution, copying or the taking of any action in reliance on the information herein is prohibited. E-mails are not secure and cannot be guaranteed to be error free as they can be intercepted, amended, or contain viruses. Anyone who communicates with us by e-mail is deemed to have accepted these risks. Company Name is not responsible for errors or omissions in this message and denies any responsibility for any damage arising from the use of e-mail. Any opinion and other statement contained in this message and any attachment are solely those of the author and do not necessarily represent those of the company.</p>
```

**EDIT**: Since some are saying this is "not possible", here is a signature image a client sent us. Picture A is in Thunderbird, Picture B is in GMail. No modification was done.

PICTURE A

[image: Pic A]

PICTURE B

[image: PIC B]

Comment: The client email with the working signature, is that an image file or base 64?

Comment: Also, how are you sending these emails? From a client like TB or from Gmail or from something else?

Comment: From web and desktop clients.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the "image to css" tool available on this web site: http://www.imgtocss.com/

Here is the result I got using the above logo:

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height=52 width=250 style="font-size:0px;height:52;width:250">
<tr>
<td>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height=52 width=50 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:0px;height:52px;width:50px">
<tr height=0>
<td width=1 />
<td width=1 />
<td width=1 />
... 
    Full code in the fiddle
...
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5tWU7/

Campaign monitor has a nice article and a breakdown of the images shown in email clients (https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/image-blocking/) as well as a nice guideline for helping with the image display issue.

Another way to get around the rule is to attach the smaller, footer images to the email. It seems that ([according to this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527555/how-can-i-force-email-programs-to-show-images-send-in-html-email-using-php)) that *"As a rule of thumb, email clients are configured to display attached images by default (e.g. those with a cid: URI scheme)..."*

Comment: Image to Css got the email out, but the logo came out sloppy and unrecognizable.

Comment: can you post an example of the converted logo?

Comment: The above CSS image preview is the same I get, but looks like the above image when I send the email.

Comment: wow... there must have been an issue with the conversion in your case. mine looked perfect and is available in the fiddle above. it's a lot of code, but minimal concern if *"always display 100% of the time no matter what"* is your caveat.

Comment: Hold on, it's not working. This is what it looks like: http://i.gyazo.com/ffa6590e1adf8622f5b5569456eaf6da.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55936/discussion-between-phlume-and-parion).

Comment: The amount of HTML generated by that tool will fill up all db's with more footer than actual email content. Email clients normally have methods of handling images, but if you go and convert them to html like that they cannot. Stick to the standard of referencing it from somewhere else instead of encoding it etc, you may end up creating other unforeseen issues.

Comment: I agree this is a lot of html, but it works. Because of that I have shared a few options here...the tool was one example. Attachments are a sure fire way to accomplish it though.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is emails weren't meant to have images historically. It was meant to be raw text.

Gmail is not blocking images only, but HTML. This is a security thing. That is why you have a safe senders whitelist essentially.

Asking your users to add you to the list will auto load the images.

Comment: actually, gmail caches images now and shows them by default.