# Email images using PHP without getting blocked

Tags: php, image, html-email

Images in email sent using PHP are not shown in the email body by default. Images get displayed only after clicking on "Show images". Is there a way to make the images in email get displayed by default without asking for users permission.

Is it completely under user's control? And will show properly only when the user adds you to their address book?

I don't think that's the case. Cause the images show properly when emailing
from gmail for example. Even if I get an email with an image from a third
party I usually don't have to click this.

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 1):

To quote [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527555/how-can-i-force-email-programs-to-show-images-send-in-html-email-using-php) which I believe sums this up well:

> As a rule of thumb, email clients are configured to display attached
>   images by default (e.g. those with a cid: URI scheme) and not load
>   remote images (which can include tracking information).
>
> If you attach all the images, then you'll usually get them showing up
>   (while inflating your SMTP bandwidth use along with that of your
>   recipients (which can make you unpopular)).

Answer (score 0):

Most email servers blocks embedded images to avoid being tracked by the sender. Gmail now uses a proxy to show all images from [Dec 2014](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html). This feature is enabled by default and images will be continue as blocked if the uses [disables this feature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en).

**Update**
Try using direct smtp connection to an email id, instead of using some third party email services.