# Background image in email template is blocked

Tags: html, css, email

When I'm adding a backgorund to email template table, all of email clients are blocking this image. How to add an image ? Domain with SSL maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Background images aren't supported in some email clients. Luckily there's a workaround for most. It sounds like you want an image as a background to a specific table cell. If so, use this code, replacing "image.jpg" for your actual image.
Note: You will need to input your image **twice** in the code below (once in the `<td>` and once in the `<v:rect>`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td background="image.jpg">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="image.jpg" color="#0c0807" />
        <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
        <![endif]-->
            <div>
            *YOUR CONTENT OR MORE TABLES GO HERE*
            </div>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:textbox>
        </v:rect>
        <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
```

This code makes your table cell house the image. Set heights or widths to suit the image. The additional conditional statements below force the image to be shown in Outlook, one of the most unreliable email clients to support background images.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am using rect and background, but in desktop clients like: Outlook, Thunderbird I get alert which blocking background http://prntscr.com/a6ocia

Comment: In that case, [try this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527555/how-can-i-force-email-programs-to-show-images-send-in-html-email-using-php). In short, you can't force the images to show.

Answer (score 0):

Designing emails that will look nice in all email clients is very time consuming and difficult.  GMail is especially difficult.  Here is a [list of css elements and their compatibility](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).  It's a great reference and I reference it each time I am designing a new email template.  It's best practice to use only tags which are supported by all clients or email services.

`background-image` is not supported in: Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010, Outlook 2013, and Outlook.com.  However, `background` is fully supported (excluding image).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am using rect and background, but in desktop clients like: Outlook, Thunderbird I get alert which blocking background prntscr.com/a6ocia

Comment: Oh, I see.  I was reading that clients may prevent images from automatically downloading if the sender isn't trusted so it may take some effort to get on the white list.  You could also try something like Amazon AWS for hosting the images.