# Mail via C# with HTML design not loaded properly in outlook

Tags: c#, html, outlook

I am facing some difficulties understanding why the mails that I'm sending through C#, containing HTML body, are not loading the images on outlook.
I can see the frame and the text, however, instead of images I see a window with red 'X' in it. And only when I press right click 'Download Image' it shows up properly.
Can you please assist ,how can I fix this issue?

Here is the code :

```
public static void SendMail(string to ,string subject, string body)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                String MailTo = to + "@oren.net.com";
                mail.From = new MailAddress("oren@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add(MailTo);
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("oren", "*******");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
```

Calling to function:

```
string mailBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("scripts/Mail.html"));
SendMail(String1, Subject, mailBody);
```

Comment: check what is the actual url to the image in the mail and if it's available for mail client to download

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force email programs to show images send in html email using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527555/how-can-i-force-email-programs-to-show-images-send-in-html-email-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get external images loaded automatically. Microsoft Outlook is configured by default to block automatic picture downloads from the Internet. You can, however, unblock pictures that you think are safe to download. See [Block or unblock automatic picture downloads in email messages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Block-or-unblock-automatic-picture-downloads-in-email-messages-15e08854-6808-49b1-9a0a-50b81f2d617a) and [Why you should block external content in Outlook by default](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/microsoft-service-agreement-virus-and-why-you-should-block-external-content/) for more information.